# How to create custom validation rule for dependent input fields in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

In my input form, I have two fields; `momentFrom` & `momentTo`. I need to put a validation which gives error message if any of the following criteria fails.

- `momentFrom` is greater than or equal to `momentTo`.
- `momentFrom` is less than now.

**My code for storing the data:**

```
public function store(Request $request, Requisition $requisitionObj) {
    $momentFrom = strtotime($request->txtTravelDate . " " . $request->txtTimeFrom);
    $momentTo = strtotime($request->txtTravelDate . " " . $request->txtTimeTo);

    $timeValidation = $requisitionObj->validateTiming($momentFrom, $momentTo);
    if ($timeValidation['error']) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $timeValidation['message'];
        return view('requisitions.create');
    } else {
        /* store form data into requisition object */
        $requisitionObj->travel_date = $request->txtTravelDate;
        $requisitionObj->moment_from = $momentFrom;
        $requisitionObj->moment_to = $momentTo;

        $requisitionObj->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('requisitions.index');
    }
}
```

I have seen laravel custom validation rules where only one field can be validated at a time. But in my scenario I need to check both fields at a time depending on each other. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: before(date) - after(date) validations will help you. Details on :  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: Can I not create custom validation to put complicated logics?

Comment: If you want custom error messages read the page : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-error-messages

Comment: Not only the message, I want to put custom validation logic before storing data. When a user tries to create a request, system has to check if any vehicle is available at that date & time. If not available, controller has to return an error message to the request form. Wondering how can I put those logic and send back the message to the form. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I have solved this problem using `FormRequest` and `AppServiceProvider`. Thought this would help others who come to this place.

First I have created FormRequest validator using following artisan command.

```
php artisan make:request StoreRequisition
```

Then added primary validation rules and messages into it.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreRequisition extends FormRequest {
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        $rules = [
        'txtTravelDate' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:today',
        'txtTimeFrom' => 'required|date_format:H:i|travel_time_validate',
        'txtTimeTo' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
        ];
        return $rules;
    }


    public function messages() {
        return [
            'txtTravelDate.required' => 'Travel date is required!',
            'txtTravelDate.date_format' => 'Invalid format for Travel Date!',
            'txtTravelDate.after_or_equal' => 'Travel Date should be today or later!',
            'txtTimeFrom.required' => 'Time From is required!',
            'txtTimeFrom.date_format' => 'Invalid format for Time From!',
            'txtTimeFrom.travel_time_validate' => 'Invalid time selected!',
            'txtTimeTo.required' => 'Time To is required!',
            'txtTimeTo.date_format' => 'Invalid format for Time To!',
            'listFunction.required' => 'Department to be selected!',
            'txtPickLoc.required' => 'Pickup Location is required!',
            'txtDropLoc.required' => 'Drop Location is required!',
            'listPurpose.required' => 'Travel Purpose to be selected!'
        ];
    }
}
```

Then inside `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider`, added the extra validation logic.

```
public function boot() {
    Validator::extend(
        'travel_time_validate',
        function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $inputs = $validator->getData();
            /* convert time to moments */
            $momentFrom = strtotime($inputs['txtTravelDate'] . " " . $inputs['txtTimeFrom']);
            $momentTo = strtotime($inputs['txtTravelDate'] . " " . $inputs['txtTimeTo']);

            $result = true;
            if ($momentFrom >= $momentTo) {
                $result = false;
            }
            return $result;
        }
    );
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function store(StoreRequisition $request, Requisition $requisitionObj) {

    $validatedData = $request->validated();

    /* store form data into requisition object */
    $requisitionObj->requester_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $requisitionObj->travel_date = $request->txtTravelDate;
    $requisitionObj->time_from = $request->txtTimeFrom;
    $requisitionObj->time_to = $request->txtTimeTo;
    $requisitionObj->purpose_id = $request->listPurpose;

    /* Finally save the record into the database */
    $requisitionObj->save();

    return redirect()->route('requisitions.index');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Creating new Rule Class**

You can create your custom rule with the artisan command: `php artisan make:rule YourRuleName`this will create a new Rule Class file into the Rules folder.

By default the created file contains a constructor, a passes method and a message method.

**Rules Logic**

If you have some complicated rules where you need the request or some models, you can pass them via the constructor.

```
  public function __construct(Request $request, User $user, ....)
    {
    //save them into class variables to access them later
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->user = $user;

    }
```

Otherwise you can directly put your validation logic into the passes method:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value){
    //some code
    return #myCondition
}
```

Last you are able to specify the message if the validation fails.

```
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Your message';
    }
```

To use your rule simply add it to your rules array:

```
$rules = [
'my_attribute' => [new MyCustomRule(),...],
]
```

Comment: This solution looks promising! I will try this and get back here with results.

Comment: But on what input it should be added? I want to run rule on specific set of inputs only once - some validator logic which depends on many inputs.

Answer (score 0):

### Example how make custom rule for validation in Laravel 8.x / Lumen 8.x.

```
public static function rules(){
    return [
       'number' => [
          'required', 'min:1', 'max:30', 'string', self::testNumber(),
       ],
    ];
}


public static function testNumber(){
    return function($attribute, $value, $fail){
        if ($value === 'foo'){
            $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
        }            
    };
}
```